# WKWebView - buttons not visible in full screen mode

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a ViewController with WebKit and two buttons above it. I want WebKit to be fullscreen and buttons to be above it.

This is code of my ViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webview: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // here I am loading URLRequest
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func loadView() {
    webview = WKWebView()
    webview.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webview
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    showLoading()
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    hideLoading()
}
```

This is what my storyboard looks like:

[image]

Methods showLoading() and hideLoading() are handling loading popup. 
With this code buttons are not visible. When I remove function loadView() buttons are visible but methods showLoading() and hideLoading() are never called.

How can I achieve mentioned behavior: fullscreen webview with buttons and functional methods (showLoading() and hideLoading())

Comment: If you want to hide it at start. In viewDidLoad() { button.isHidden = true }

Comment: I want buttons to be visible.

Comment: you override the `view` property with your `WKWebView` instance... obviously all subviews (=buttons) of your old view will be removed as well – you need to consider adding it as a subview only, and insert it under the buttons in the view-hierarchy.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But I don't know how to do that. I tried using view.addSubview(webview) but it didn't work too. Entire ViewController was not loaded at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what happens in your current code is you arbitrarily **replace** the current view with your `webview` instance and that directly removes the current view's subviews (=your buttons) as well.

---

you can either

## a)

insert the webview directly:

```
override func loadView() {
    webview = WKWebView()
    webview.navigationDelegate = self
    view.insertSubview(webview, at: 0)
    webview.frame = view.bounds
}
```

or

## b)

add the `WKWebView` to your view in the *Interface Builder* under your buttons then connect the outlet and the delegate(s) from *IB* and you can remove your `loadView()` implementation entirely.